# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Здравствуйте!

Имеется код. Нужно поочередно открывать файлы. Проблема в том, что при попытке его выполнения, вылазит ошибка:

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'.

Так вот, почему `list`? Если при открытии пути из цикла, в переменной `f` мы получаем объект типа `str`

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем проблема. Спасибо.

```
path = glob.glob("C:\...\*.txt")

with open("sample_text_collection_metadata.txt", "w", encoding = "utf-8") as metadata_out:
    for txt in path:
        f = open(txt, "r", encoding = "utf-8").read()
        autor_name = f.split("Autor:")[1].replace("\r", "").split("\n")[0]
        text_file = f.split("Title:")[1].replace("\r", "").split("\n")[0]
        file_name = f.split("/")[-1]
        metadata_out.write(file_name + "\t" + autor_name + "\t" + text_file + "\n")
        f.close()
```

Comment: Точно в этом месте ошибка происходит? Вроде в приведенном коде все в порядке.

Comment: Именно в этом. А точнее когда доходит до "autor_name = f.split("Autor:")[1].replace("\r", "").split("\n")[0]". Я специально скопировал код в отдельный модуль и попробовал запустить оттуда. Сам ума не приложу в чем проблема ...

Comment: так посмотрите что в этот момент в переменной f находится, чтобы код был вида  `f = '...'; autor_name = f.split...` - и вам будет проще ошибку увидеть, и нам проверять проще

Comment: При вывводе текста в IDLE отображается текст книги, но без кавычек вначале и в конце. При проверке `type(f)`  пишет `<class 'str'>`.

Comment: И еще одно забыл уточнить. Сначала пишет `IndexError: list index out of range`,  но после того как убрать единицу[1] в `f.split("Autor:")[1]` пишет `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`. И все-таки `replace` а не `split`.

Comment: @PyMan, это называется не "уточнить". Очевидно проблема в том, что f.split("Autor:") возвращает список длиной 1. Это значит, что в f нет подстроки "Autor:".

Comment: @dzhioev Все верно. Нехватало одной буквы в условии ... Как мог недоглядеть, ума не приложу ... Спасибо большое Вам и всем отозвавшимся.

Comment: просмотров много